# Confusion on networking service start/stop in Ubuntu

Tags: service, ubuntu-11.04

I'm preparing to move and took down two of my servers, leaving only one with some essential services running. What I neglected to consider was that one was the DHCP server(which I realized when somebody contacted me saying they couldn't connect. Whups). So because I only have a few hosts on this small network, I opted to just statically configure them for now. One of these is a new Ubuntu 11.04 server, where I have very little experience.

I edited `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/hosts` to reflect my changes.

I ran

```
$sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
 *deconfiguring network interfaces ...
```

So yay. Then I try to start, it gives me the mumbo jumbo about using services (why didn't it do that for the stop?) So instead I run ...

```
$sudo service networking start
networking stop/waiting
```

Now, to me that says the status of the service is stopped. But when I ping another computer, I get a successful reply. So is it not actually stopped? More importantly, am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**

```
daniel@FOOBAR:~$ sudo service networking status
networking stop/waiting

daniel@FOOBAR:~$ sudo service networking stop
stop: Unknown instance:

daniel@FOOBAR:~$ sudo service networking status
networking stop/waiting

daniel@FOOBAR:~$ sudo service networking start
networking stop/waiting

daniel@FOOBAR:~$ sudo service networking status
networking stop/waiting
```

So you can see why I ran /etc/init.d/networking stop instead. For some reason upstart (that is what "services" is, right?) isn't working with `stop`.

`cat /etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       FOOBAR
198.3.9.2       FOOBAR #Added entry July 19 2011

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
#       hostname FOOBAR

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 198.3.9.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 198.3.9.0
        broadcast 198.3.9.255
        gateway 198.3.9.15
```

No I didn't save backups, it was just a minor change so I just commented out the old DHCP setting.

**Edit**
I set everything back to original settings and set up a DHCP server. "starting" networking does the *same* thing. I can only assume this is normal, I just don't know WHY. It can't be anything to do with the configuration files, since they've been restored.

Comment: Okay, so we've established that I know nothing about Ubuntu configuration. ^_^ Let's try this on for size: What's your /etc/network/interfaces look like?

Comment: I'm pretty sure rc.conf is arch specific. I'm fairly certain hosts, interfaces, and resolv.conf are the only files I should be concerned with, unless this is an issue with upstart. There's an rc.local ...

Comment: Edit you post with the information of these commands, in this order : 1 - service networking status
2 - service networking stop
3 - service networking status
4 - service networking start
5 -service networking status

Comment: btw, if you want to stop and start again your service, try running service networking restart. And you said that you edited your /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/hosts, can you show them? (did you made a backup for these before changing them?)

Comment: Yeah, I tried service networking restart first, it returned "restart: Unknown instance:" I'll post the rest in a sec.

Comment: And if you try the same manipulation but with /etc/init.d/networking. But it seem that your modification are in fault. Try to rename or comment one of your FOOBAR in your hosts.

Comment: My understanding was that 127.0.1.1 was another pointer to localhost in ubuntu (why it's there I don't know ...) I'll comment it and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, commenting that out has no effect on the service and its magic status (stopped but working ...) but I can't ping anything but localhost unless I remove the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use `/sbin/ifconfig` to see what your current networking state is.

Use `/sbin/ifup <name>` to bring up an interface defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Likewise use `/sbin/ifdown <name>` to bring the interface down.

---

If the actual state of the interface is different from that of `ifconfig` do the following:

**DO NOT DO THIS OVER THE NETWORK. DO THIS FROM THE CONSOLE. IF YOU LOSE ACCESS TO YOUR BOX YOUR BLOOD IS ON YOUR OWN HEAD.**

1. Clear the entry from `/etc/network/run/ifstate`.
2. For each IP on that interface run `/sbin/ip addr del 1.2.3.4/24 dev eth0` (obviously using the appropriate IP & interface name).
3. For the interface itself run `/sbin/ip link set eth0 down` (again, using the appropriate interface name).

After this is done you should be able to cleanly use `/sbin/ifup <name>` to bring the interface up.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sudo service network-interface restart INTERFACE=eth0
```

edit the command to use your interface instead of `eth0` if necessary.

(I've checked mine with `ifconfig`, but mine is up.)

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1706192